# How does a pytorch function (such as RoIPool) work?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, torchvision

For example, I'm trying to view the implementation of **RoI Pooling** in pytorch.

Here is a code fragment showing how to use RoIPool in pytorch

```py
import torch
from torchvision.ops.roi_pool import RoIPool

device = torch.device('cuda')

# create feature layer, proposals and targets
num_proposals = 10
feature_map = torch.randn(1, 64, 32, 32)

proposals = torch.zeros((num_proposals, 4))
proposals[:, 0] = torch.randint(0, 16, (num_proposals,))
proposals[:, 1] = torch.randint(0, 16, (num_proposals,))
proposals[:, 2] = torch.randint(16, 32, (num_proposals,))
proposals[:, 3] = torch.randint(16, 32, (num_proposals,))

roi_pool_obj = RoIPool(3, 2**-1)
roi_pool = roi_pool_obj(feature_map, [proposals])
```

I'm using pychram, so when I follow `RoIPool` from the second line, it opens a file located at `~/anaconda3/envs/CV/lib/python3.8/site-package/torchvision/ops/roi_pool.py`, which is exactly the same as codes in the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/vision/main/_modules/torchvision/ops/roi_pool.html#roi_pool).

I pasted the code below without documentations.

```py
from typing import List, Union

import torch
from torch import nn, Tensor
from torch.jit.annotations import BroadcastingList2
from torch.nn.modules.utils import _pair
from torchvision.extension import _assert_has_ops

from ..utils import _log_api_usage_once
from ._utils import convert_boxes_to_roi_format, check_roi_boxes_shape


def roi_pool(
    input: Tensor,
    boxes: Union[Tensor, List[Tensor]],
    output_size: BroadcastingList2[int],
    spatial_scale: float = 1.0,
) -> Tensor:

    if not torch.jit.is_scripting() and not torch.jit.is_tracing():
        _log_api_usage_once(roi_pool)
    _assert_has_ops()
    check_roi_boxes_shape(boxes)
    rois = boxes
    output_size = _pair(output_size)
    if not isinstance(rois, torch.Tensor):
        rois = convert_boxes_to_roi_format(rois)
    output, _ = torch.ops.torchvision.roi_pool(input, rois, spatial_scale, output_size[0], output_size[1])
    return output


class RoIPool(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, output_size: BroadcastingList2[int], spatial_scale: float):
        super().__init__()
        _log_api_usage_once(self)
        self.output_size = output_size
        self.spatial_scale = spatial_scale

    def forward(self, input: Tensor, rois: Tensor) -> Tensor:
        return roi_pool(input, rois, self.output_size, self.spatial_scale)

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        s = f"{self.__class__.__name__}(output_size={self.output_size}, spatial_scale={self.spatial_scale})"
        return s
```

So, in the code example:

When running `roi_pool_obj = RoIPool(3, 2**-1)` it will create an instance of `RoIPool` by calling its `__init__` method, which only initialized two instance variables;

When running `roi_pool = roi_pool_obj(feature_map, [proposals])`, it must have called the `forward()` method (but I don't know how) which then called the `roi_pool()` function above;

When running the `roi_pool()` function, it did some checking first and then computed output with the line `output, _ = torch.ops.torchvision.roi_pool(input, rois, spatial_scale, output_size[0], output_size[1])`.

But this doesn't show details of how roi_pool is implemented and pycharm showed `Cannot find declaration to go to` when I tried to follow `torch.ops.torchvision.roi_pool`.

To summarize, I have two questions:

1. How does the `forward()` called by running `roi_pool = roi_pool_obj(feature_map, [proposals])`?
2. How can I view the source code of `torch.ops.torchvision.roi_pool` or where is the file containing it's implementaion located?

Last but not least, I've just started reading source code which is pretty difficult for me. I'd appreciate it if you can also provide some advice or tutorials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `RoIPool` is a subclass of torch.nn.Module. Source code:

https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/07ae61bf9c21ddd1d5f65d326aa9636849b383ca/torchvision/ops/roi_pool.py#L56

2. nn.Module defines `__call__` method which in turn calls `forward` method. Source code:

https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/b2311192e6c4745aac3fdd774ac9d56a36b396d4/torch/nn/modules/module.py#L1234

3. When you executing `roi_pool = roi_pool_obj(feature_map, [proposals])` statement the `__call__` method uses the `forward()` of RoiPool. Source code:

https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/07ae61bf9c21ddd1d5f65d326aa9636849b383ca/torchvision/ops/roi_pool.py#L67

4. `RoiPool.forward` calls `torch.ops.torchvision.roi_pool`.

https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/07ae61bf9c21ddd1d5f65d326aa9636849b383ca/torchvision/ops/roi_pool.py#L52

5. ops is a object which loads native libraries implemented in c++:

https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/b2311192e6c4745aac3fdd774ac9d56a36b396d4/torch/_ops.py#L537

so when you call `torch.ops.torchvision` it will use `torchvision` library.

6. Here the `roi_pool` function is registered:

https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/7947fc8fb38b1d3a2aca03f22a2e6a3caa63f2a0/torchvision/csrc/ops/roi_pool.cpp#L53

7. Here you can find the actual implementation of `rol_pool`

CPU:

https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/7947fc8fb38b1d3a2aca03f22a2e6a3caa63f2a0/torchvision/csrc/ops/cpu/roi_pool_kernel.cpp

GPU:
https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/7947fc8fb38b1d3a2aca03f22a2e6a3caa63f2a0/torchvision/csrc/ops/cuda/roi_pool_kernel.cu